# Error while downloading 'http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd' to C:\Users\Myacc\.lsp4xml\cache\http\maven.apache.org\xsd\maven-4.0.0.xsd.XML

Tags: java, maven, model-view-controller

I am new to maven, 
I have installed apache-maven-3.6.1 
using it via visual studio code
First creating workspace was throwing error due to maven was behind proxy
I updated setting.xml in maven, added proxy and workscpace was created by vsc

Its a fresh workspace, but the pom.xml is throwing error in first project tag as mentioned in title

I searched and added the same settings.xml file in C:\Users\Myacc.m2 folder and checked

I deleted the m2 folder and checked

I executed mvn clean package in project directory

none of it worked

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

this the xml tag which is throwing error

From browser I am able to access
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd

I could not find .lsp4xml\cache\http\maven.apache.org , thought of keeping the xsd manually

Comment: ".lsp4xml\cache\http" looks weird it should be ".m2\repository\" instead in your home directory

Comment: I agree, but its just like that, I dont know where its taking this path

Comment: I tried the similar setup in my personal home laptop, having admin right, this folder "C:\Users\Myacc\.lsp4xml\cache\http\maven.apache.org\xsd" was created already having xsd in it  ---and the code is working fine as well in this pc

Comment: tried to copy this folder along with xsd in office pc, but no luck, still showing same error

Answer (score 13):

For the same problem, I found this solution.
changed http to https in below line in pom file. worked in eclipse. Not sure why.

```
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org...
```

Comment: Yes, this seemed to be a bug in the STS when creating a new Maven Project. I tried a few other hacks, but this was the simple and best :) Basically the xmlns attribute has two values within a double quote, and both of them were not in sync - as one was referring to http and other was https. Keeping them in sync did the trick. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Changing https to http made it work
Note the difference in xsi:schemLocation

Incorrect:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Correct:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth I see same error (firewall related?) which I think is due to the XML parser LSP4XML - rather than a Maven issue. The useSystemProxies suggestion here worked for me: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-xml/issues/134

Comment: In Eclipse 2020-06, I was able to fix this by adding the line `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` to *eclipse.ini*.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is still following for the solution.

Issue: Admin Rights

Solution: Run the eclipse in admin mode in Windows and issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried many ways to fix the error but failed, and you are using corporate network, a possible reason could be your company has blocked the download of Maven.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Running eclipse as admin solves this issue pretty well

Answer (score 0):

It is related to Admin rights. You can follow one of solutions to fix problem:

1. Open Eclipse as a administrator
2. You can replace https to http on pom.xml
   `*https:*//maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd`   => `**http:**//maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd`